# Plotting a vector field with polar coordinates on a ring

Tags: plotting

Assuming I have a vector components: A_r(r,theta) and A_t(r,theta) so A=(A_r,A_t)
I would like to show the Vector A on a ring. for some reason when I'm using VectorPlot it has to be in cartesian coordinates. So I have define A_x and A_y from A(r,t) and tried to use VectorPlot yet it shows nothing.
the line:

```
VectorPlot[{ar[r, t], at[r, t]}, {r, R1, R2}, {t, 0, 2pi}]
```

shows a vector field, yet it is not on a ring.
when I'm trying to use the cartesian coordinates:

```
VectorPlot[{FullSimplify[ax[x, y]], FullSimplify[ay[x, y]]}, {x, -R2, R2}, {y, -R2, R2}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, R1^2 < x^2 + y^2 < R2^2]]
```

It shows nothing.
I have made the transformation by

```
A_x=A_r[sqrt(x^2+y^2),Arctan[x,y]]*(x/sqrt(x^2+y^2))-A_t[sqrt(x^2+y^2),Arctan[x,y]]*(y/sqrt(x^2+y^2))


A_y=A_r[sqrt(x^2+y^2),Arctan[x,y]]*(y/sqrt(x^2+y^2))+A_t[sqrt(x^2+y^2),Arctan[x,y]]*(x/sqrt(x^2+y^2))
```

For some reasons it does not work,
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

For the lower edition.

```
ar[r, t] = r*t;
at[r, t] = r + t;
polar2cartesian = 
  TransformedField[
   "Polar" -> "Cartesian", {ar[r, t], at[r, t]}, {r, t} -> {x, y}];
cutpolar2cartesian = 
  polar2cartesian*Boole[1/2 <= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 2];
VectorPlot[cutpolar2cartesian // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

**Original**

Maybe one way is use `TransformedField` to translate the `Polar` to `Cartesian`.

```
ar[r, t] = r*t;
at[r, t] = r + t;
polar2cartesian = 
  TransformedField[
   "Polar" -> "Cartesian", {ar[r, t], at[r, t]}, {r, t} -> {x, y}];
VectorPlot[polar2cartesian // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, 
   1/2 <= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 2 && -π <= ArcTan[x, y] <= π]]
```

[image]

Comment: We can also set `ar[r, t] = r;at[r, t] =0;` or `ar[r, t] = 0;at[r, t] =t;` to test the method.

Comment: I think the problem is with the RegionFunction.
I have used TransformedField to get ax and ay, when I use
'Plot3D[Evaluate[polar2cartesian], {x, -R2, R2}, {y, -R2, R2}]'
results are shown, yet when RegionFunction is added, it shows nothing, also when using RegionFunction in VectorPlot.
 It has to be done on a ring because for r=0 ax and ay are large so there are no other vectors.

Comment: @jonathan test the updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it, using the cartesian components, given as a function of polar coordinates:

```
vec[r_, phi_] = 
 r {-Sin[phi], Cos[phi]}; (*cart. comp. of vector field*)
dat = Flatten[
  Table[{r { Cos[p], Sin[p]}, vec[r, p]}, {r, 0.6, 1, 0.1}, {p, 0, 
    2 Pi , Pi/6}], 1];
ListVectorPlot[dat, VectorPoints -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't have the definitions of your functions, so unforutnately I can't use those in my answer, but here is an example that might get you started:

```
ring = Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 2}];

VectorPlot[
  {2 x + y, x - y^2}, {x, y} ∈ ring,
  Prolog -> {FaceForm[LightGray], EdgeForm[Black], ring}
]
```

[image: vector plot output overlaid on the annulus domain]

Comment: For some reason the function Annulus gets the code to stuck

Comment: @jonathan Gotta give us some more info there to troubleshoot the problem...